# TSQL - Group by latitude and longitude and average speed

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, average

I have got this SQL query

```
SELECT 
    [machine], 
    [speed], 
    Round([latitude], 3)  AS Latitude, 
    Round([longitude], 3) AS Longitude 
FROM
    [position] WITH (nolock) 
WHERE  
    (attime BETWEEN '20170606 8:00' AND '20170606 20:00' ) 
    AND machine IN (SELECT DISTINCT [machine] 
                    FROM [haul] WITH (nolock) 
                    WHERE ([timestart] BETWEEN '20170606 8:00' AND '20170606 20:00') 
                      AND machine IN (72)) 
    AND [speed] > 0
```

And it returns a data set like:

```
ID    SPEED   LAT     LON
-----------------------------
72 - 3,6  - 14,368 - 26,898
72 - 14,4 - 14,368 - 26,898
72 - 28,8 - 14,368 - 26,898
72 - 32,4 - 14,368 - 26,897
```

But I need to get the average speed and co-ordinates as well in order to see records like:

```
ID    SPEED   LAT     LON
---------------------------
72 - 15,6 - 14,368 - 26,898   
72 - 32,4 - 14,368 - 26,897
```

When I try this query:

```
SELECT 
    [machine], 
    Avg([speed]) AS Speed, 
    Avg(Round([latitude], 3)) AS Latitude, 
    Avg(Round([longitude], 3)) AS Longitude 
FROM   
    [wdata_position] WITH (nolock) 
WHERE
    (attime BETWEEN '20170606 8:00' AND '20170606 20:00') 
    AND machine IN (SELECT DISTINCT [machine] 
                    FROM [wdata_haul] WITH (nolock) 
                    WHERE ([timestart] BETWEEN '20170606 8:00' AND '20170606 20:00') 
                      AND machine IN (72)) 
    AND [speed] > 0 
GROUP BY 
    [machine], [speed], latitude,  longitude
```

It reduced the quantity of rows from 3,926 to 3,883 and I saw this data set:

```
72  3,59999990463257    14,357  26,898
72  3,59999990463257    14,359  26,901
72  3,59999990463257    14,359  26,901
72  3,59999990463257    14,366  26,899
72  3,59999990463257    14,368  26,899
72  3,59999990463257    14,368  26,898
72  3,59999990463257    14,368  26,898
72  3,59999990463257    14,368  26,898
72  3,59999990463257    14,368  26,9
```

It is not what I need at all.

How can I change my SQL to achieve my goal?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't see any `GROUP BY` or `AVG` keywords in that query. Did you try something? Did you encounter a problem? What's with NOLOCK, do you really want to read *dirty data*? `NOLOCK` means that your query will read dirty data that may be rolled back, NOT that it won't take any locks

Comment: What's the point of `AND Machine IN (SELECT ...)` when `Machine can only be 72 ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have tried `AVG`  for SPEED LAT and LON but it does not reduce the number of rows as I need.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Just ignore it `AND Machine IN (SELECT ...)`

Comment: Tried how? What did you write? AVG calculates the average over a set of rows. It's GROUP BY that groups that set

Comment: Please post the actual query, what you tried, what failed etc.  It almost sounds like you are asking how to use `SELECT AVG(.) GROUP BY Machine`. On the other hand, you can't average *coordinates*. There's no such thing when talking about multiple dimensions. Taking the average of each dimension won't return the geometric mean

Comment: If you want the average by ID, you group only by ID. Use `GROUP BY MACHINE` only

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I need average by coords and speed together

Comment: And that's what you get if you use only `GROUP BY MACHINE`. I suspect that you should check how SQL and grouping behaves. I also suspect you have blocking issues that you tried to cover up with `NOLOCK`.

Comment: Have you **tried** writing a proper GROUP BY? Have you tried `SELECT  [Machine] , AVG([Speed]) AS Speed,  ROUND(AVG([Latitude]),3) AS Latitude, ROUND(AVG([Longitude]),3) AS Longitude
FROM [WDATA_POSITION] 
WHERE AtTime between '20170606 08:00' and '20170606 20:00' AND Machine =72 AND [Speed] > 0
GROUP BY  [Machine] ` ? Why are you adding speed and coordinates in `GROUP BY` when *these* are the values you want to average?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos If I do like you suggets then I exclude another coords that I have to display.

Comment: What other coordinate? It's impossible to help if you don't fully explain the problem. In any case it's not what I suggest. You want to average by Machine? You want the average speed per *location* perhaps? Then group by `Machine, Lat, Lon`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the data you're looking at (for example, how can the speed change for machine 72 when the lat/long coordinates remain the same?), but I think I understand what you are trying to do anyway.

It sounds like you want to get the average of "speed" for each unique combination of machine, latitude and longitude?

If so, then you just need to modify your query to group by those columns, so that only the speed is being aggregated (using Average):

```
SELECT [machine], 
       Avg([speed])          AS Speed, 
       Round([latitude], 3)  AS Latitude, 
       Round([longitude], 3) AS Longitude 
FROM   [wdata_position] WITH (nolock) 
WHERE  ( attime BETWEEN '20170606 8:00' AND '20170606 20:00' ) 
       AND machine IN (SELECT DISTINCT [machine] 
                       FROM   [wdata_haul] WITH (nolock) 
                       WHERE  ( [timestart] BETWEEN '20170606 8:00' AND 
                                                    '20170606 20:00' ) 
                              AND machine IN ( 72 )) 
       AND [speed] > 0 
GROUP  BY 
       [machine], 
       Round([latitude], 3), 
       Round([longitude], 3)
```

Comment: You can remove the subquery completely, since it returns 72 or nothing

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I don't know the logic behind that subquery, but that could be valid. It's not really relevant to the question.

Comment: Hi bro! Thanks for the input! As you see in my question I need to AVG speed  if there are identical coords. I mean if there are 3 rows for LAT:12.333 and LON:14.555 I need to display 1 row only and not 3 and display AVG speed as well for this row. Would you mind to revise your answer pls? Is it possible to  archiveit  by using 1 query only or the logic is more complicated itself in this case?

Comment: @DmitryBoyko isn't that what Natthan's query does already? Given the data in the question it returns only one row per coordinate

Comment: The query above should do that unless I have missed something about your data. If you only want a single row per lat/long then you will have to remove [machine] from the results and group by, because including that means you will get one row per machine/lat/long.

Comment: @DmitryBoyko explain your actual business problem, not how you think it should be solved. Post the actual input data and what you want the output to look like